# Finder window, exit search options

Tags: macos, finder, search

When using Command-F to search in a Finder window, what is the shortcut to disable the search and return to the standard finder window?

For example:

1) Navigate to specific folder
2) Command-F to search
3) Finder window is now search specific

How can I exit from having a search specific finder window and simply see what is in the current folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Back arrow, top left, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>

[image]

You can also return to your search with the forward arrow or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>]</kbd>